# Image of simply connected open set is simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity

I feel the following assertion does not hold but I did not come up with an counter-example so far.

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is continuous. Furthermore, suppose $X$ is simply connected. So $f_\star:\pi(X,x_0)\to\pi(Y,f(x_0))$. The question is whether $\exists U\ni f(x_0)$ which is simply connected where $U$ is some set(I hope).

I do not see any reason to hope $\pi(Y,f(x_0))=1$ here. Furthermore $f(X)\to Y$ is continuous map from subspace topology. So I truly want $f:X\to f(X)$ inducing $f_\star:\pi(X,x_0)\to\pi(f(X),f(x_0))$. There is no hope for homeomorphism. So I still cannot conclude triviality of $\pi(f(X),f(x_0))$.

Q1: Is my expectation correction?

Q2: What is the counter-example or what are essential ingredient to construct such a counter-example? It looks I need to somehow make sure $Z\to \pi(f(X),f(x_0))$ injection minimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $X=\mathbb R$, $Y=S^1$, and $f(x)=e^{ix}$. Then $X$ is simply connected, but $f(X)(=S^1)$ isn't.

Answer (score 2):

For an injective counterexample: Let $X=\{0\}$ and $f:X \to S^1$ be the inclusion map.

For a surjective counter example: Let $X=[0,1]$ and consider the quotient map that identifies endpoints of $X$, so that we get a map $f:X \to S^1$ that is continuous, but $\pi_1(S^1)$ is nontrivial.

For a bijective counterexample: Consider the map $[0,1) \to S^1$ that winds it around the circle. It is continuous and bijective, but has no continuous inverse.